# How to change the default time zone in R?

Tags: r, timezone, date-arithmetic

How can I change the default timezone in R?
I'm working with time series.  All my time series are defined in UTC time zone, but if I print a date it is always done in CET/CEST time zone.

Comment: Have you read `?timezone` and tried anything therein?

Comment: I had a similar problem and needed a fast solution. I used the Jupyter for R. It is set up probably for a UTC time zone.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Another way to do it, without changing the whole computer time is using the setenv command like this : `Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')`

Comment: On a Mac, when you reset the R session, this seems to go away and is back to ""

Comment: For other regions you can use [this timezone list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). I used `Sys.setenv(TZ = "America/Sao_Paulo")` and worked nice.

Comment: @Jas That is correct, the R session doesn't (and shouldn't) save the process environment. Another approach is needed for people who rely on saving/restoring the session.

Answer (score 14):

See this good article on changing time zone in R:

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html

Shortly (in case the link will be unavailable in the future):

```
# your time string
pb.txt <- "2009-06-03 19:30"
# convert it to R object for London time zone
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz="Europe/London")
# convert it to PDT time zone
format(pb.date, tz="America/Los_Angeles",usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2009-06-03 11:30:00 PDT"

# can be also done for many date at once
d <- c("2009-03-07 12:00", "2009-03-08 12:00", "2009-03-28 12:00", "2009-03-29 12:00", "2009-10-24 12:00", "2009-10-25 12:00", "2009-10-31 12:00", "2009-11-01 12:00")
t1 <- as.POSIXct(d,"America/Los_Angeles")
cbind(US=format(t1),UK=format(t1,tz="Europe/London"))

     US                    UK                   
[1,] "2009-03-07 12:00:00" "2009-03-07 20:00:00"
[2,] "2009-03-08 12:00:00" "2009-03-08 19:00:00"
[3,] "2009-03-28 12:00:00" "2009-03-28 19:00:00"
[4,] "2009-03-29 12:00:00" "2009-03-29 20:00:00"
[5,] "2009-10-24 12:00:00" "2009-10-24 20:00:00"
[6,] "2009-10-25 12:00:00" "2009-10-25 19:00:00"
[7,] "2009-10-31 12:00:00" "2009-10-31 19:00:00"
[8,] "2009-11-01 12:00:00" "2009-11-01 20:00:00"
```

Answer (score 10):

What operating system?

In general, see `help(Startup)` as you can set values via `.Renviron` and its site-wide variant.

But you should probably set this for your machine as a whole, which under Linux may alter the file `/etc/timezone`, and on Windows you'd set a system-wide environment variable `TZ`.

Lastly, if your *formatted* display of dates and time shows CET/CEST, this may already be set as a system default and your question really is how to set your UTC times correctly in your R objects.

Comment: I did change my windows configuration. And I also had to change in R the R environment variable TZ like this : `TZ="UTC"`. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7):

I found @Dirk's answer very useful for Ubuntu, so I thought I would expand on it.

From `help(Startup)` we see that environment variables are set by the `Renviron.site` file:

> Unless --no-environ was given on the command line, R searches for site and user files to process for setting environment variables. The name of the site file is the one pointed to by the environment variable R_ENVIRON; if this is unset, ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site’ is used

We can find the path to `R_HOME` by using the function `R.home()`, which in my case returns:

```
> R.home()
[1] "/usr/lib/R"
```

Therefore, the `Renviron.site` file is found (for me) in `/usr/lib/R/etc/`.

Simply open this file, and insert the line:

```
TZ="UTC"
```

or similar.

Comment: This is an awesome answer to "permanently" set the timezone in R. But what I don't get: why is it even showing this message? My R: v3.4.2 on macOS High Sierra.