# R: index() or index.xts() changes the values of Date of a time series, why?

Tags: r, date, indexing, time-series, xts

I would like to extract the dates from a time series obtained using getSymbols
but when I used the index / index.xts function the returned dates appear to be one day earlier.
I cannot understand why this behavior happens in the following code.

However, the intended behavior is to obtain a list of Date object corresponding to the one in the original time series.

Here is the code, note the last date of the time series SPY is 24 Aug 2012 but the last  value from the index(SPY) call is 23 Aug 2012:

```
getSymbols("SPY")

tail(SPY)

    SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2012-08-17   142.23   142.30  141.86    142.18   90813700       142.18
2012-08-20   141.98   142.22  141.59    142.19   78255700       142.19
2012-08-21   142.54   143.09  141.45    141.76  105581100       141.76
2012-08-22   141.40   142.05  141.07    141.82  132999200       141.82
2012-08-23   141.47   141.48  140.44    140.66  111406800       140.66
2012-08-24   140.31   141.83  140.22    141.51   99431500       141.51 

tail(index(SPY))

[1] "2012-08-16" "2012-08-19" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23"

tail(index.xts(SPY))

[1] "2012-08-16" "2012-08-19" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23"
```

Thank you to everybody that could reply to my post.

Additional info on the session

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rbenchmark_0.3.1             fGarch_2110.80.1            
 [3] fBasics_2160.81              MASS_7.3-20                 
 [5] timeSeries_2160.95           timeDate_2160.95            
 [7] tseries_0.10-29              quadprog_1.5-4              
 [9] PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.4.4 quantstrat_0.6.8            
[11] blotter_0.8.10               FinancialInstrument_0.15.2  
[13] quantmod_0.3-17              TTR_0.21-1                  
[15] Defaults_1.1-1               xts_0.8-6                   
[17] zoo_1.7-7                    lubridate_1.1.0             
[19] stringr_0.6.1                plyr_1.7.1                  
[21] XML_3.9-4.1                 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       ggplot2_0.9.1     
 [5] grid_2.15.1        labeling_0.2       lattice_0.20-6     memoise_0.1       
 [9] munsell_0.3        proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1    
[13] scales_0.2.1       stabledist_0.6-4   tools_2.15.1     


> getDefaults(getSymbols)
NULL
> getSymbolLookup("SPY")
NULL
> showSymbols()
 SPY     GSPC      IBM      XLF      XLP      XLE      XLY      XLV      XLI 
 "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo" 
     XLB      XLK      XLU      IEF     AAPL      DIA     MSFT      IWM      EEM 
 "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo" 
     EFA      GLD      AGG      HYG      FXE      FXY      VXX      VXZ      HIG 
 "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo" 
    VTI      VEU      VNQ      DBC      XAU     gold     Gold STOXX50E     GOLD 
"yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "oanda"  "oanda"  "oanda"  "yahoo"  "yahoo" 
     VIX  DEXUSEU   EURUSD  DEXKOUS    EUR=X    INR=X 
 "yahoo"   "FRED"  "oanda"   "FRED"  "yahoo"  "yahoo"
```

Also note that I have installed some R code from the Systematic Investor blog, systematicinvestor.wordpress.com, by using the commands

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
con = gzcon(url('systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
source(con) 
close(con)
```

SOLUTION PLUS ADDITIONAL QUESTION

GSee user found the answer (Thank you!) pointing out that in my session I have masked index.xts. So a solution is to call xts:::index.xts(SPY) instead of just index.xts(SPY) to override the masking.
In fact the command

```
> tail(xts:::index.xts(SPY))
```

returns the right answer

[1] "2012-08-17" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23" "2012-08-24" –

The answer now prompted another question: given below the code for the "masking/overriding" index.xts function (that returns the wrong answer moving the dates one day earlier):

```
> index.xts
function (
x           # XTS object
)
{
temp = attr(x, 'index')
class(temp)='POSIXct'   
if( attr(x, '.indexCLASS')[1] == 'Date')
    temp = as.Date(temp)
return(temp)
}
```

Why is this function returning the wrong results when called as tail(index.xts(SPY)) ? What is wrong with the code of this index.xts function?

Compare the two output (the first one is wrong while the second provide the right answer):

```
tail(index.xts(SPY))

[1] "2012-08-16" "2012-08-19" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23"

tail(xts:::index.xts(SPY))
[1] "2012-08-17" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23" "2012-08-24"
```

Thanks again for your time and attention.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question.  Also, show the output of `getDefaults(getSymbols)` and `getSymbolLookup("SPY")` if either of them are not `NULL` and the output of `showSymbols()`

Comment: Thank you GSee for replying to my message, I have updated it with the additional information about the session data

Comment: It looks like you may have masked `index.xts`.  What happens if you use `tail(xts:::index.xts(SPY))`?

Comment: also note that I have installed some R code from the Systematic Investor blog, http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/, by using the command    setInternet2(TRUE);
con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'));
source(con);
close(con)

Comment: GSee, you have found the problem! here is the output                 > tail(xts:::index.xts(SPY))
[1] "2012-08-17" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23" "2012-08-24"

Comment: GSee, I have appended at the post a further question about the code of the "wrong" index.xts, if you feel like having a look. Thanks!

Comment: To further confirm. The R code from the Systematic Investor blog, systematicinvestor.wordpress.com redefines the 
index.xts function causing the wrong answer.

Comment: I'm using xts (0.9-7), and invoking the index() command seems to get the date/time objects wrong when I do not set the TZ environment variable. Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-timezone-in-r Changing my timezone to GMT helped me get the times right. It was '' on my Ubuntu system. In some cases, a lag of even one day can occur, and corrupt your dataset, therefore I think it's a good idea to check if you're getting the right times with xts objects. The strange thing is, the objects may display differently before/after using index or .index* fun

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is that you have run some code that masks the `index.xts` method from the **xts** package.  In the comments of your OP, you told us you ran this code

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
source(con)
close(con)
```

After running that code, `index.xts` has been redefined (actually, masked) to be

```
> index.xts
function
(
        x                       # XTS object
)
{
        temp = attr(x, 'index')
        class(temp)='POSIXct' 

        if( attr(x, '.indexCLASS')[1] == 'Date')
                temp = as.Date(temp)
        return(temp)
}
```

If you compare that to the `xts:::index.xts` function that is being masked, you can see that it is quite different.  So, you can no longer expect the same results.

If you download the code from systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz, and look at it, you'll see this comment

```
###############################################################################
# Fast alternative to index(x) for XTS object
# NOTE index.xts is the same name as the index function in the XTS package
###############################################################################
```

So, it appears that the author did this intentionally in hopes of making it faster.  Unfortunately, he has also made it less robust.

This code actually gives me the same result as `xts:::index.xts`, so I'm not 100% certain of why you're getting different results using it.  But, my guess is that it has to do with changing the class from `numeric` to `POSIXct` and then converting back to `Date`

Anyway, I'd probably run

```
rm(index.xts)
```

after sourcing that code to remove this "enhancement."

Comment: +1 and great example of why _not_ doing packages sucks. Which I tried before to tell the author of `sit.gz`, but seemingly without too much success.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, Several months ago, I asked nicely for that author to make a package as well.  He said he would...

Comment: Thank you for your replies Gsee and Dirk, could you point out what is wrong with the index.xts code in the sit.gz? I have appended the code in the main post. I cannot understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: yes GSee I have seen your guess. Thank you. However I would like to understand exactly what is wrong with the code of index.xts (from sit.gz). Because if the problem is due to class conversions then it is a problem of R and not of sit.gz.

Comment: Simply, that is not the right way to convert `numeric` to `POSIXct`.  There is an `as.POSIXct` function for that.

Comment: Thank you GSee. Very detailed and precise answer.

Comment: `xts:::index.xts` accounts for timezone differences, while the "faster" code does not.  That's why some people can't replicate this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth opening a clean copy of R.  I get (with R 2.15.0):

```
> require(quantmod)
> getSymbols("SPY")
[1] "SPY"
> tail(SPY)
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2012-08-17   142.23   142.30  141.86    142.18   90813700       142.18
2012-08-20   141.98   142.22  141.59    142.19   78255700       142.19
2012-08-21   142.54   143.09  141.45    141.76  105581100       141.76
2012-08-22   141.40   142.05  141.07    141.82  132999200       141.82
2012-08-23   141.47   141.48  140.44    140.66  111406800       140.66
2012-08-24   140.31   141.83  140.22    141.51   99431500       141.51
> index(tail(SPY))
[1] "2012-08-17" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23" "2012-08-24"
> tail(index(SPY))
[1] "2012-08-17" "2012-08-20" "2012-08-21" "2012-08-22" "2012-08-23" "2012-08-24"
> tail(index.xts(SPY))
Error in tail(index.xts(SPY)) : could not find function "index.xts"
```

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you for trying my code. I agree with your suggestion, but I would like to understand what happen with my code to avoid that the same problem happens again in the future. I have updated my post with data on my session, if it may be of help in understanding what caused the problem.