# Download-Save-Load roundtrip with Quantmod in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to download data using quantmod, save them to files to be loaded later.

The following piece of R code

```
library(quantmod)

symbols <- c("DEXUSUK", "STLFSI", "GDP")
tmpdir <- tempdir()

getSymbols(symbols, src="FRED")
saveSymbols(symbols, file.path=tmpdir)

rm(list = symbols)

getSymbols(symbols, src="RData", dir=tmpdir, extension="RData")
```

produces an error on the last line:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("DEXUSUK.Open", "DEXUSUK.High",  : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Yet valid .RData files get created in the temp. location and can be load()-ed individually.

Is this a problem in quantmod (using version 0.4-3 on R 3.1.2) or is this usage invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `col.names`

```
getSymbols(symbols, src="RData", dir=tmpdir, extension="RData", col.names="Close")
#[1] "DEXUSUK" "STLFSI"  "GDP"
```

Comment: `saveSymbols.days` or `saveSymbols.common` in conjunction with `getSymbols.FI` is an alternative.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12239000/967840)