# Read CSV in R, but Keep Character Row Names

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using the popular R library "quantmod" and cannot figure out how to keep the character row names when I read the file to a csv.

For instance, I will have some data as follows:

```
ROW NAME       VALUE
1970-05-08     .05
1970-08-01     .05
1970-12-10     .06
...            ---
```

When I use

```
write.csv(MyData,'MyData.csv', row.names = T)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Column One     Column Two
1               .05
2               .05
3               .06
...             ---
```

How do I keep the character row name? I.e. how can value 1 in the csv actually read as 1970-05-08?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add dput(MyData) to your post? the answer depends on what exactly MyData is

Comment: at a glance, probably you are looking for the saveSymbols function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613295/download-save-load-roundtrip-with-quantmod-in-r

Comment: I can't understand from your question title and body whether you're trying to read a CSV, or write one. Consider `read.csv.zoo()` and/or `write.zoo()`.

Comment: I am writing a csv. The data "MyData" shown above with the row names, is being pulled in from yahoo finance. I am trying to write that data to a csv, which works but I want to preserve the text from the row name, and not have it converted to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware that `quantmod` returns `xts-objects`. So the first column (the dates) is the index. To write `xts-objects` to a, say `csv-file`,  the easiest way is to use the `write.zoo` function.

```
getSymbols('AAPL',from='2018-01-01’)
write.zoo(AAPL,'aapl.csv',sep=',',quote=FALSE)
```

`quotes=FALSE` removes the quotes around the column names.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

You'll need to store the desired character row names as a new column in your data frame prior to exporting it as a .csv file.

To avoid a redundant column, set `row.names = FALSE` inside the [`write.csv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) function. When importing the data frame back into [r](/questions/tagged/r), set `row.names` in [`read.csv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to the name of the column which represents your desired row name values .

## Reproducible Example

Here, the row names are a character, representing the [movie in which each Star Wars character dies](http://listofdeaths.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars).

```
# create data
df <-
  data.frame( ID = 1:3
              , Name = c( "Anakin", "Han", "Luke" )
              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# create row names
rownames( df ) <- c( "Episode_VI", "Episode_VII", "Episode_VIII" )

# view data
df
#              ID   Name
# Episode_VI    1 Anakin
# Episode_VII   2    Han
# Episode_VIII  3   Luke

# store rownames in new column
df$row.names <- rownames( df )

# export data as CSV
write.csv( x = df
           , row.names = FALSE
           , file = "Star_Wars_data.csv"
)

# import data from CSV
df.csv <- read.csv( file = "Star_Wars_data.csv"
                , header = TRUE
                , row.names = "row.names"
                , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# view data from CSV
df.csv
#              ID   Name
# Episode_VI    1 Anakin
# Episode_VII   2    Han
# Episode_VIII  3   Luke

# end of script #
```

## Save as RDS File

Also, you can use [`saveRDS()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) to export your data frame as an .rds file. This method does not require you to store the row names as a column; rather, it simply saves is when importing into [r](/questions/tagged/r) using [`readRDS()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html).

```
# create data
df <-
  data.frame( ID = 1:3
              , Name = c( "Anakin", "Han", "Luke" )
              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# create row names
rownames( df ) <- c( "Episode_VI", "Episode_VII", "Episode_VIII" )

# view data
df
#              ID   Name
# Episode_VI    1 Anakin
# Episode_VII   2    Han
# Episode_VIII  3   Luke

# Export as RDS file
saveRDS( object = df
         , file = "Star_Wars_data.rds"
)

# view data
readRDS( file = "Star_Wars_data.rds" )
#              ID   Name
# Episode_VI    1 Anakin
# Episode_VII   2    Han
# Episode_VIII  3   Luke

# end of script #
```