# Converting character in date/time format (POSIXct) works on Windows not Linux

Tags: linux, r, datetime, strptime

I can't figure out why the following line of R script works perfectly fine on Windows (7, 64bit with R 3.0.2 64bit) but not on Linux (3.12.1-1-ARCH GNU/Linux 64bit with R 3.0.2 64bit):

Windows:

```
>strptime("2013-05-08 10:27:50", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>[1] "2013-05-08 10:27:50"
```

Linux:

```
> strptime("2013-05-08 10:27:50", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>NA
```

There is some reference to "LC_TIME locale category" in the description of [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) but I really don't know if this is relevant to my problem.

Could somebody please explain, why the same line of code leads to different results and how I can make the Linux version of R behave the way of the Windows version?

Comment: Is the timezone the same on both machines? See `?Sys.timezone`.

Comment: Works for me on Linux - must be something to do with your particular Linux system's configuration. Try `export LC_ALL=C` in the shell before starting R.

Comment: No, it is not. Linux shows me "" and Windows "CET". Any idea how to change that?

Comment: For comparison you could try this in Python: `import datetime; datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-05-08 10:27:50", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` (it works for me on Mac OS).

Comment: export LC_ALL=C doesn't change anything. I have the feeling, I have to somehow tell R, which timezone I'm at.

Comment: Thanks for the Python reference but this particular code line is from an R script I've written at work, where it works perfectly fine. Now I want it to work on my private Linux laptop.

Comment: Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6408072/3027391 I've changed the timezone of R to CET and Sys.timezone() now shows "CET" on Linux like on Windows. Still, the line of code does not work and shows NA.

Comment: ... Hmm, had I better posted this question to "CrossValidated"? It is rather a system problem and less a statistical problem. Guess I should have used the R mailing list.

Comment: Works fine on FreeBSD 10.0 and Windows...

Comment: Works on R-3.1.1, linux-3.11.0, with no timezone reported in R (`Sys.timezone() # NA`). Isn't CrossValidated more for pedagogical discussions? I'd think this is very much a StackOverflow (if an R problem) or SuperUser (if system based) issue.

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest version, do you still have this problem?

Comment: I've switched from Arch to Debian and it is working now with the default R installation (R 3.1.1 64bit)!

Answer (score 0):

It works in Arch Linux with 3.17.6-1-ARCH and R-3.1.2. My timezone is set as Asia/Kolkata but the output is slightly different, it shows the timezone as well.

`strptime("2013-05-08 10:27:50", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2013-05-08 10:27:50 IST"`.