# How to add the time to a date when using as.date?

Tags: r

I have measurements that were taken at this time: `13880` and they represent `"days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00"`

So now I want to know the dat and time:

```
as.Date(13880, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2008-01-02"  # works fine
```

Now to add the time:

```
as.Date(13880, origin="1970-01-01",tz = "UTC",  format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

or

```
as.POSIXct(13880, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "1970-01-01 04:51:20 CET"
as.POSIXlt(13879, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "1970-01-01 04:51:19 CET"
```

None of these worked for me. Any idea?

Comment: How would you know the time if `13880` is measured in days?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, not sure about this case but I remember in Excel dates are stored as numbers (like 13880 for example) and the hours are fractions of that, so for example 13880.5 would be date X + 12 hours (half a day) - as in the answer by C8H10...

Comment: @docendodiscimus Possible, don't know.

Comment: Why not just `as.POSIXct(as.Date(13880))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date("1970-01-01") + 13880) # returns "2008-01-01 19:00:00 EST"
as.POSIXct(as.Date("1970-01-01") + 13880.5) # returns "2008-01-02 07:00:00 EST"
```

You can also set your time zone:
[How to change the default time zone in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-time-zone-in-r)
also: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `as.Date` result depends on your systems default time zone (in your case is "EST"), while `13880` were measured in days, so where should you take the time from?

Comment: @DavidArenburg the OP states that the starting time is 00:00 on 1970-01-01 (but does not specify TZ, so assuming UTC, which is the default input to `?as.Date`).  My interpretation is that time should be taken from fractional days (the .5 of 13880.5 in the above example) and added to midnight --so adding half a day would get you to 12:00 UTC or 07:00 EST.

Comment: You maybe right, then you probably should specify `tz` within `as.Date` then