# How to maintain time zone with POSIX DateTime and avoid NAs introduced by coercion in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, posixct

I create a time series dataframe that I will use to merge other time series data into.

```
dates2010 <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010-06-15 00:00:00", tz = "GMT"), as.POSIXct("2010-09-15 23:00:00", tz = "GMT"), by="hour")  # make string of DateTimes for summer 2010
dates2011 <- seq(as.POSIXct("2011-06-15 00:00:00", tz = "GMT"), as.POSIXct("2011-09-15 23:00:00", tz = "GMT"), by="hour")  # make string of DateTimes for summer 2011
dates <- c(dates2010, dates2011)                           # combine the dates from both years
sites <- c("a", "b", "c")                                  # make string of all sites
datereps <- rep(dates, length(sites))                      # repeat the date string the same number of times as there are sites
sitereps <- rep(sites, each = length(dates))               # repeat each site in the string the same number of times as there are dates 
n <- data.frame(DateTime = datereps, SiteName = sitereps)  # merge two strings with all dates and all sites
n <- n[order(n$SiteName, n$Date),]                         # re-order based on site, then date
```

If I run the above code, 'dates2010' and 'dates2011' are in GMT format: `dates2010[1]` "2011-06-15 00:00:00 GMT".
But when I create the object 'dates' for some reason format switches to EST: `dates[1]` 
"2010-06-14 19:00:00 EST"

Maybe it has something to do with POSIX classes?

```
class(dates2010)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I attempted to [change the default time zone for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-time-zone-in-r) to GMT to avoid time zone switching problems.  This results in an NA coersion error when I attempt to order the data frame 'n' and merge other data frames into 'n'.

```
n <- n[order(n$SiteName, n$Date),]
Warning message:
In xtfrm.POSIXct(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any thoughts on how I might keep time zones constant and avoid the NA coercion errors?  Thank You!

Comment: `?DateTimeClasses`: _Using `c` on "POSIXlt" objects converts them to the current time zone, and on "POSIXct" objects drops any "tzone" attributes (even if they are all marked with the same time zone)._  Apparently there's no way to avoid it, so you just have to reset the attribute after the fact as shown below.

Comment: Your method worked @Rich Scriven to change 'dates' time zone to "GMT".     `dates <- structure(c(dates2010, dates2011), tzone = "GMT")`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh wow.  Thank you for that information @alistaire.

Comment: Also, if you are bad at remembering attribute names or just like lubridate, its `with_tz` function does the same thing: `dates <- lubridate::with_tz(c(dates2010, dates2011), 'GMT')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c()` drops attributes. So when you created `dates`, the time zone was dropped and it automatically defaulted to the current locale.  Fortunately you can use `structure()` and set the time zone there.

```
dates <- structure(c(dates2010, dates2011), tzone = "GMT")
head(dates)
# [1] "2010-06-15 00:00:00 GMT" "2010-06-15 01:00:00 GMT" 
# [3] "2010-06-15 02:00:00 GMT" "2010-06-15 03:00:00 GMT"
# [5] "2010-06-15 04:00:00 GMT" "2010-06-15 05:00:00 GMT"
```

If `dates` was already created, you can add/change the `tzone` attribute later.

```
attr(dates, "tzone") <- "GMT"
```