# Calculating an hour average between 12 and 1AM with per min dataframe: dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, lubridate

I have a per minute timeseries for a number of years.

I need to compute a the following value for each minute data point:

q <- (Fn-Fd)/Fn

Whereby Fn is the average F value at night time between 12-1 AM and Fd is just the minute data point.

Now obviously the Fn changes each day so one approach would be to calculate Fn perhaps using a dplyr function and i would need to create a loop of some kind or re-organise my data frame...

dummy data:

```
#string of dates for a one month
datetime <- seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00:00", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2012-2-1 0:00:00", tz="UTC"),
     by="min"
) 

#variable F
F <- runif(44641, min = 0, max =2)

#dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(datetime,F))
library(lubridate)
#make sure its in  "POSIXct" "POSIXt" format
df$datetime <- as_datetime(df$datetime)
```

Or a less elegant way might be to get Fn on its own, between the times using dplyr first - i think it will be something like this:

```
Fn <- df %>% 
  filter(between(as.numeric(format(datetime, "%H")), 0, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(hour=format(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:")) %>%
  summarise(value=mean(df$F))
```

But I am not sure my syntax is correct there? Am I calculating the mean F between 12 and 1 AM per day?

Then i could just print the average Fn value for each min per day to my dataframe and do the simple calculation to get Q.

Thanks in advance for advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Date = as.Date(datetime)) %>%
  mutate(F_mean = mean(F[hour(datetime) == 0]), 
         value = (F_mean - F)/F_mean) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-F_mean, -Date)


#             datetime     F  value
#   <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2012-01-01 00:00:00 1.97  -0.902
# 2 2012-01-01 00:01:00 0.194  0.813
# 3 2012-01-01 00:02:00 1.52  -0.467
# 4 2012-01-01 00:03:00 1.66  -0.599
# 5 2012-01-01 00:04:00 0.765  0.262
# 6 2012-01-01 00:05:00 1.31  -0.267
# 7 2012-01-01 00:06:00 1.62  -0.565
# 8 2012-01-01 00:07:00 0.642  0.380
# 9 2012-01-01 00:08:00 1.62  -0.560
#10 2012-01-01 00:09:00 1.68  -0.621
# ... with 44,631 more rows
```

We first `group_by` every date get the `mean` value for 0th hour (values between 00:00 to 00:59) each day and calculate `value` using the formula given.

Comment: That's great - thank you! Just to clarify on the breakdown of the syntax for my own better understanding - what does the last aspect of the code do - the ungroup() and select()? - thanks for your help

Comment: @Lmm Since we are doing grouping it by `Date`, the grouping would still remain in the dataframe if we don't `ungroup()` it and `select` with `-` sign drops the additional columns which we don't need.

Comment: Great thank you. Also can we include an na.rm into the mean calculation? e.g. mutate(F_mean = mean(F[hour(datetime) == 0], na.rm = T) would that work?

Comment: @Lmm yes, you can include that and it will remove all the `NA` values.

Comment: One issue i have literally just come across is this seems to be working in UTC time, i am trying to work in Cad mountain time - is there anyway I can specify my time zone within this function? As currently my F_mean appears at 6pm on the previous day.

Comment: you can change the default timezone using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-time-zone-in-r

Comment: Hmmm, that still doesnt seem to work - my date time within my dataframe is Canada/mountain and i have used Sys.setenv(TZ= "Canada/Mountain") but from the mutate function (F_mean = mean(F[hour(datetime) == 0]) is still considering 18:00 - which would be 0 in UTC as the hour to average? Could i specify within the mutate function? ... also really, thank you for all the help ;)