# determine the time zone when building a singularity image

Tags: timezone, singularity-container

I am trying to build an image using singularity. in one step I have to run a R script to do so, in the recipe file I need to install R and I did using the following command:

```
apt-get install -y systemd systemd-sysv gdebi-core procps libssl1.1 ed wget curl libqt5webkit5 libqt5core5a libxml2-dev r-cran-xml wget libssl-dev curl libcurl4-openssl-dev libnetcdf-dev netcdf-bin libcairo2-dev libxt-dev default-jre texlive-latex-base libhdf5-dev r-base r-base-dev
curl https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb > /rstudio-1.1.463-amd64.deb
apt-get -y install /rstudio-1.1.463-amd64.deb
wget -O /rstudio-server-stretch-1.1.463-amd64.deb \
https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-stretch-1.1.463-amd64.deb
gdebi -n /rstudio-server-stretch-1.1.463-amd64.deb
```

and I run the recipe file using this command:

```
sudo singularity build nanos.sif Singularity.recipe
```

but after running it, at some point it asks me that which time zones I am located at and here is the message:

```
Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa        6. Asia            11. System V timezones
  2. America       7. Atlantic Ocean  12. US
  3. Antarctica    8. Europe          13. None of the above
  4. Australia     9. Indian Ocean
  5. Arctic Ocean  10. Pacific Ocean
Geographic area:
```

I chose one of them using name and numbers but building did not proceed. do you know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To me the following spell worked

```
%environment
  TZ=UTC
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 
%post
    export TZ=UTC
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y  .....
```

Replace `.....` with your packages. No worries about the specific timzone. Normally it should be taken from the host system, so UTC will be overridden unless you instruct singularity otherwise at the run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this via the `TZ` environment variable in %post. e.g., `export TZ=UTC`. You may also need to set `TZ=UTC` (or the desired timezone) in %environment as well.

See [additional info on timezones in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html) and a related question: [How to change the default time zone in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-time-zone-in-r)