# Change the default behaviour of as.Date

Tags: r, timezone

I live in Sydney and use a database that often stores dates as POSIXcts.

as.Date is frequently used, but to get correct values, it has to be `as.Date(x, tz = "My/Timezone")`.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

I've attempted creating the function

`as.Date <- function(x, ...){zoo::as.Date(x, ..., tz = "Australia/Sydney")}`

but this doesn't work well with the implementation of `as.Date` that targets numeric entries or unusual date formats (e.g. `as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y")` would break as the default first argument is `tz` which is not a format).

Is there a fix?

I've seen this: [How to change the default time zone in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-time-zone-in-r) but it seems to address a different issue: my timezone is correct, but the as.Date function doesn't care about my timezone.

Comment: Does `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")`   show the correct time zone for you?

Comment: It would help to see examples of dates which are "numeric entries".

Comment: @neilfws, I've added an example of a case where it breaks.

Comment: Does this work? `as.Date <- function(x, ...) base::as.Date(x, tz = "Australia/Sydney", ...)`

Comment: @ekoam, same issue using base - `as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y")` no longer gives the expected result

Comment: Perhaps it iwould be sufficient to use `as.Date(format(x))`  Another approach if you want to redefine `as.Date` only for POSIXct inputs is to  redefine `as.Date.POSIXct`.